# PHP htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities() with exception

Tags: php, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

How can I define an exception for `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` ?
I would like to have all special characters converted to be HTML safe except for `<strong><b><i><em><br>`

Comment: You could replace those tags with something else, call `htmlspecialchars()`, then put back the tags.

Comment: Why don't you just use something like bbCode?

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't `strip_tags()` take care of that or am I not grasping the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to convert your string with `htmlentities` and then use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace back the selected tags:

```php
<?php
$string = '<p><strong>A <i>test</i> string with a <a href="#">Test link</a></strong></p>';
$encoded_string = htmlentities($string);

$encoded_string = preg_replace('/&lt;(\/?(strong|b|i|em|br))&gt;/', '<$1>', $encoded_string);

echo($encoded_string); 
//outputs: &lt;p&gt;<strong>A <i>test</i> string with a &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;Test link&lt;/a&gt;</strong>&lt;/p&gt;
```

Of course if you want to handle arguments inside the tags as well, then the regex pattern needs some work, although these tags are generally lacking any argument.

Comment: Thanks @MrLumie - I was doing something similar with multiple str_replace() but this is much cleaner and elegant so I'll adopt this solution

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified the solution by @MrLumie by adding another `(.?\/)?` to retain both `<br>` and `<br />` (albeit converting them both to `<br>`):

```
/&lt;(\/?(strong|b|i|em|br))(.?\/)?&gt;/i
```

as shown here: https://regex101.com/r/G6D2lj/1

Comment: Move the second `(.?\/)?` into the second capture group, and you'll retain it after the replace. Also it would be wise to add \s* between elements to ensure it is captured with any sort of stray white-space.

Comment: @MrLumie how do you mean? I tried `&lt;(\/?(strong|b|i|em|br))\s*(.?\/)?&gt;` but it yelded a <brbr>

Comment: Sorry, I meant first capture group. Anything that's inside the first capture group will remain untouched after the replace. So like this: `&lt;(\/?(strong|b|i|em|br)(.?\/)?)&gt;`

Comment: That makes sense @MrLumie - so where were you suggesting to add the \s*?